# How can I use fixtures from "dummy" in my Rails engine tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rails-engines

I've created a Rails engine

`> rails plugin new my_engine --mountable`

In the dummy app, I create a model and fixtures...

`> cd test/dummy`
`> rails generate resource Owner name:string`

I ensure there is fixture data.
I write a test in the dummy app to make sure fixtures are working.
`test("owners"){assert Owner.all.count > 0 }`

It fails.

So, **how does one use fixtures from test/dummy to test an engine?**

---

Note I have opened an issue on github where this is being discussed: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [discussion I've had on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19477):

1. `rails generate ...` from within the dummy app is basically doing the wrong thing when it puts fixtures in dummy/test/fixtures.
2. Fixtures can only live in one directory.

The solution then, is move them manually to the engine's test/fixtures directory. Or patch Rails.